# Autocomplete doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to create a autocomplete but when I'm typing a surname in the textfield, it doesn't show the full name.

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#txtBuscar").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
          selectFirst: true
      });
 });
```

PHP:

```
  require('conecta.php');
ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
$cSQL="SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS FROM personas WHERE APELLIDOS LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY APELLIDOS";
$stmt=$oConni->prepare($cSQL) or die($oConni->error);
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$_GET['q']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($nombre,$apellidos);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        echo $apellidos.', '.$nombre."\n";

    }
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: What does the php show if you call it from the location bar or look in the NET tab of f.ex. Chrome

Comment: Make sure the PHP is returning a JSON object with fields `label`, `value`, or both.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI autocomplete? If so, that's not the correct syntax.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete Please look at jquery autocomplete manual..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `?` parameter in your `LIKE` argument doesn't get filled in since it is in a string. If you're using MySQL, try something like this:

```
$cSQL="SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS FROM personas WHERE APELLIDOS LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ORDER BY APELLIDOS";
```

For Oracle, use something like this:

```
$cSQL="SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS FROM personas WHERE APELLIDOS LIKE '%' || ? || '%' ORDER BY APELLIDOS";
```

Comment: RESOLVED:the solution is as said @Marcellus